# WordPress Contact Form 7 how to explode a date form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, contact-form

I have this:

`[date* SERVICE_DATE id:pickup class:field1]`

It's Contact Form 7, and in the email it shows like this:

`Pick_up_Date: [SERVICE_DATE] - Year/Month/Day`

...and I receive this email:

`Pick_up_Date: 2017-03-27 - Year/Month/Day`

But when I had it on a PHP/HTML site, I was able to explode the date and get each date by explode, like this:

```
        $pickup     = explode("/",$_POST['SERVICE_DATE']);

        Service_Day: '.$pickup[0].' 

        Service_Month: '.$pickup[1].' 

        Service_Year: '.$pickup[2].'
```

How can I make this work exactly that explode way in WordPress with Contact Form 7?

Comment: Your php code will be  work on wordpress. Just run your code inside `<?php     //your code here      ?>`

Comment: thanks for te quick answer, i see just need to paste that on the form, or in the email html section?

Comment: No, that will not work. You will need to hook into CF7 using one of the hooks provided. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a predefined hook in Contact Form 7 to modify the data before send. Look into using the `before_send_mail` hook.

Here is an example:

```
add_action( 'wpcf7_before_send_mail', 'wpcf7_modify_date' );

function wpcf7_modify_date($contact_form){

    // get current SUBMISSION instance
    $submission = WPCF7_Submission::get_instance();


    // Ok go forward
    if ($submission) {

        // get submission data
        $data = $submission->get_posted_data();

        // nothing's here... do nothing...
        if (empty($data))
            return;

        // get mail property
        $mail = $contact_form->prop( 'mail' ); // returns array with mail values

        /*
         * based on your current date display, you will explode by "-" rather than "/"
         * see: https://contactform7.com/date-field/ for information on how to change your date format
         *
         * NOTE: If you change your date format, you will have to change this function.
         */
        $exploded_date = explode("-", $data['SERVICE_DATE']);

        $year = $exploded_date[0];
        $month = $exploded_date[1];
        $day = $exploded_date[2];

        // Modify mail body
        $mail['body'] .= "Service_Day:" . $day . "\n";
        $mail['body'] .= "Service_Month:" . $month . "\n";
        $mail['body'] .= "Service_Year:" . $year . "\n";

        // set mail property with changed value(s)
        $contact_form->set_properties( array( 'mail' => $mail ) );

        return $contact_form;
    }
}
```

This function will hook into the submitted form values before the email is sent, explode the submitted date and then display it as you would like. You should remove `Pick_up_Date: [SERVICE_DATE] - Year/Month/Day` from your CF7 email settings in wp-admin as this will add the date to the email body automatically.

**EDIT:** To place the date at the beginning of the email, do this:

```
// Assign the current mail body to a new variable
$mail_body = $mail['body'];

// Override the $mail['body'] with the new content
$mail['body'] = "Service_Day:" . $day . "\n";
$mail['body'] .= "Service_Month:" . $month . "\n";
$mail['body'] .= "Service_Year:" . $year . "\n";

// Append the original body below the new body
$mail['body'] .= $mail_body;
```

Comment: Thanks very much i will test it and give feedbakc

Comment: If this solution worked for you feel free to accept the answer :)

Comment: ok Ty Bailey thanks a lot for this, its working perfectly.. now need to figure out how to make it show in a exactly position.. because is showing after all my body message.. any ideas?

Comment: I've edited my answer to show you how to include it at the start of the email rather the end. Unfortunately there is no way to position it in the middle unless you write all of your content in the `$mail['body']` variable and not in wp-admin.